# Mysql error on debian 8 after import .sql

Tags: mysql, reload

I have a big problem with my mysql I already reinstall the machine 3 times, always the same error.
I've switched from debian 7 to 8 so I use mysqldump to export my database (8Giga) and import it, since import is here the error I get

```
    mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: active (running) since lun. 2017-07-17 13:18:35 CEST; 1s ago
  Process: 11765 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11690 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/mysql reload (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11854 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           ├─10797 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
           └─11179 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/v...

juil. 17 13:18:35 WorldCube.fr mysql[11854]: Starting MySQL database server: mysqld already running.
juil. 17 13:18:35 WorldCube.fr systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
```

Comment: have you tried disabling the service? or is this when you try and enable it?

Comment: Yes command start and stop works

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the `mysql server`, the file which you are trying to import is having problem, in the middle its stopping the `mysql daemon` and trying to restart it.

I would suggest that, break that file into multiple small scripts and try importing it or use `mysql workbench` to import the database script into your `mysql server` the file.